# Installing Android System-App on Emulator does not work

Tags: android, android-emulator, system-services

I have a System App that is capable of performing some system level tasks (Ex: remote reboot etc.). I want to try this out in the Android-Dev-Studio Emulator.

I have googled for it and this is what I've found so far:

Build the .apk

- adb remount
- adb push [MyApp.apk] /system/app/ *(this is **/system/priv-app** in API Level 19+)*
- adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/[MyApp.apk]
- adb reboot

I have done all of this. I've tried copying my apk to both folders "/system/app/" and "/system/priv-app/" folders. Regardless, when I reboot the emulator does not show anything and gets stuck.

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456561/cant-get-android-app-installed-as-system-app-on-emulator-to-get-past-securityex) reboot does not work for emulators which I also noticed to be correct, since the copied .apk file is lost upon restart.

What am I missing here?

I am compiling and building for SDKVersion - 21. So which folder should I copy my system app to? (/system/app/ or /system/priv-app)?

Also if reboot does not work for emulators, how do I get the app installed and running?

Answer (score 0):

What's android version of your emulator?
The "/system/app/" and "/system/priv-app/" directory structure have been changed since Android L, you should use:

```
adb push MyApp.apk /system/priv-app/MyApp/
```